# SetCameraInfo successfully called but no change in /camera_info topic

Tags: ros, call-service, camera-info, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to write a little C++ package to apply custom made calibration files to my indigo system using the following code (inspired by [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/43623/how-to-call-service-set_camera_info-of-gscam-package/) thread):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/SetCameraInfo.h>
#include <camera_calibration_parsers/parse.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "apply_camera_info");
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    ROS_INFO("usage: apply_camera_info <camera topic> <calibration file>");
    return 1;
  }

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << argv[1] << "set_camera_info";
  std::string s = oss.str();

  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<sensor_msgs::SetCameraInfo>(s);

  std::string camera_name = argv[1];
  std::string filename = argv[2];    
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo camera_info;

  camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibration(filename, camera_name, camera_info);      
  
  sensor_msgs::SetCameraInfo srv;
  srv.request.camera_info = camera_info;


  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    std::ostringstream sss;
    sss << srv.request.camera_info;
    ROS_INFO("%s", sss.str().c_str());
    ROS_INFO("Calibration successfully applied.");
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service <camera>/set_camera_info");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Actually the code seems to work fine. ROS_INFO returns the correct camera_info values after running the command.
However, when I run `rostopic echo /camera_info` in another tab, I still get the old values. So no update is actually taking place.

Would you have any suggestions for me?
Btw: I am using a ueye camera.

Thanks
Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221084/setcamerainfo-successfully-called-but-no-change-in-/camera_info-topic/) by [pennjamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25106/pennjamin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-11-17**:
What camera driver are you using this with? The service call will also return a `SetCameraInfoResponse` which has a status and status message which might be informative. Also make sure the service exists before calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you Dan Lazewatsky for the useful hints,

the srv.status_message returned "Error formatting camera_info for storage", so I checked the documentation of the ueye camera node.

It turned out, that the calibration file I was using doesn't match the formatting standard of the camera node. After using a default calibration file it worked.

For completeness I post the optimized code below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/SetCameraInfo.h>
#include <camera_calibration_parsers/parse.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "apply_camera_info");
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    ROS_INFO("usage: apply_camera_info <camera topic> <calibration file>");
    return 1;
  }

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::ostringstream ossSet;
  ossSet << argv[1] << "set_camera_info";
  std::string s = ossSet.str();
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<sensor_msgs::SetCameraInfo>(s);

  std::string camera_name = argv[1];
  std::string filename = argv[2];

  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo camera_info;
  camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibration(filename, camera_name, camera_info);

  sensor_msgs::SetCameraInfo srv;
  srv.request.camera_info = camera_info;

  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    if(srv.response.success)
    {
      std::ostringstream ossInf;
      ossInf << srv.request.camera_info;
      ROS_INFO("%s", ossInf.str().c_str());
      ROS_INFO("Calibration successfully applied.");
    }
    else
    {
      std::ostringstream ossStm;
      ossStm << srv.response.status_message;
      ROS_ERROR("%s", ossStm.str().c_str());
      return 1;
    }    
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service camera/set_camera_info");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [pennjamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25106/pennjamin/) with karma: 26 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1